# Using jQuery $(this) with ES6 Arrow Functions (lexical this binding)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

Using ES6 arrow functions with lexical `this` binding is great.

However, I ran into an issue a moment ago using it with a typical jQuery click binding:

```
class Game {
  foo() {
    self = this;
    this._pads.on('click', function() {
      if (self.go) { $(this).addClass('active'); }
    });
  }
}
```

Using an arrow function instead:

```
class Game {
  foo() {
    this._pads.on('click', () => {
      if (this.go) { $(this).addClass('active'); }
    });
  }
}
```

And then `$(this)` gets converted to ES5 (self = this) type closure.

Is a way to have Traceur ignore "$(this)" for lexical binding?

Comment: this seems like a perfect example of when not to use an arrow function since `.on()` does indeed have a `this` value useful to you.  To me it's much clearer with `this` referring to the event target than having to pass the event and find the target manually.  I haven't played much with arrow functions but it does seem like it would be confusing to go back and forth with anonymous functions.

Answer (score 245):

This has nothing to do with Traceur and turning something off; this is simply how ES6 works. It's the specific functionality you're asking for by using `=>` instead of `function () { }`.

If you want to write ES6, you need to write ES6 all the time. You can't switch in and out of it on certain lines of code, and you definitely cannot suppress or alter the way `=>` works. Even if you could, you would just wind up with some bizarre version of JavaScript that only you understand and which would never work correctly outside of your customized Traceur, which definitely isn't the point of Traceur.

The way to solve this particular problem is not to use `this` to gain access to the clicked element, but instead use `event.currentTarget`:

```
Class Game {
  foo(){
    this._pads.on('click', (event) => {
      if(this.go) {
        $(event.currentTarget).addClass('active');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

jQuery provides `event.currentTarget` specifically because, even before ES6, it is not always possible for jQuery to impose a `this` on the callback function (i.e. if it was bound to another context via [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Comment: Note, though it only diverges for delegated `.on` calls, `this` is actually `event.currentTarget`.

Comment: Is this answer ok? Like loganfsmyth noted, `this` == `event.currentTarget`. No?

Comment: @LéonPelletier No. `this` and `event.currentTarget` are the same unless `this` is bound to the enclosing scope, as with an ES6 arrow function.

Comment: if you want to save some code, you can also also destructure it: 
    ({currentTarget}) => { $(currentTarget).addClass('active') }

Comment: *"If you want to write ES6, you need to write ES6 all the time."* That's....a very suspect statement. ES2015+ is entirely backward-compatible *(other than a **very** small number of **very** edge cases)*. You can mix `class X` and assigning to things on `X.prototype`, to pick a random example. You can keep using `var` (though I woudln't), or using the `var x = this;` thing instead of arrow functions (though I wouldn't). Etc. What you *can't* do is use `this` for two different things simultaneously. :-)

Answer (score 72):

Event binding

```
$button.on('click', (e) => {
    var $this = $(e.currentTarget);
    // ... deal with $this
});
```

Loop

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call($items, (el, index, obj) => {
    var $this = $(el);
    // ... deal with $this
});
```

Answer (score 68):

## Another case

The answer by meagar is correct and I've up-voted it.

However, there is another case:

```
$('jquery-selector').each(() => {
    $(this).click();
})
```

Could be fixed as:

```
$('jquery-selector').each((index, element) => {
    $(element).click();
})
```

This is a historical mistake in jQuery which puts the **index**, instead of the *element* as the first argument:

> #### .each( function )
>
> **function**
> Type: `Function( Integer index, Element element )`
> A function to execute for each matched element.

See: https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function

Also applies to  `.map( function )` and `.filter( function )`.

Comment: Ah ha! This just saved me a bunch of headache, thank you!

Answer (score 10):

As [Meager](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229044/meagar) said in his answer on this same question [If you want to write ES6, you need to write ES6 all the time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27670450/7719176),

so if you are using arrow function of ES6: `(event)=>{}`, then you have to use `$(event.currentTarget)` instead of `$(this)`.

you can also use more nicer and cleaner way of using currentTarget as  `({currentTarget})=>{}`,

```
Class Game {
  foo(){
    this._pads.on('click', ({currentTarget}) => {
      if(this.go) {
        $(currentTarget).addClass('active');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

originally this idea was commented by [rizzi frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1680899/rizzi-frank) in meagar's answer, and i felt it useful and i think that not all people will read that comment so i have written it as this another answer.

Answer (score 9):

*(This is an answer I wrote for another version of this question, before learning it was a duplicate of this question. I think the answer pulls together the information fairly clearly so I decided to add it as a community wiki, although it's largely just different phrasing of the other answers.)*

You can't. That's half the point of arrow functions, they close over `this` instead of having their own that's set by how they're called. For the use case in the question, if you want `this` set by jQuery when calling the handler, the handler would need to be a `function` function.

But if you have a reason for using an arrow (perhaps you want to use `this` for what it means outside the arrow), you can use `e.currentTarget` instead of `this` if you like:

```
class Game {
  foo(){
    this._pads.on('click', e => {                   // Note the `e` argument
      if(this.go) {
        $(e.currentTarget).addClass('active');      // Using it
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The `currentTarget` on the event object is the same as what jQuery sets `this` to when calling your handler.