# jQuery $(this) is "undefined" on a nodejs module (using Browserify)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ecmascript-6, browserify

I created the following `NodeJs` module :

```
import $ from 'jquery';

module.exports = () => {

  $("#clients-table tbody tr").click(() => {

    let $this = $(this);

    console.log($this);
    console.log($(this));
    console.log($(this).attr("class"));
    console.log($("#clients-table tbody tr").attr("class"));
    console.log("end");
  });
}
```

and my `Browserify` entry point looks like this:

```
"use strict";

import $ from 'jquery';
import test from './test';

test();
```

When I click on the element, the click event is triggered, but `$(this)` is `undefined`.
Here's the result of different `console.logs`:

```
test.js:9 he.fn.init {}
test.js:10 he.fn.init {}
test.js:11 undefined
test.js:12 test
test.js:13 end
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using jQuery $(this) with ES6 Arrow Functions (lexical this binding)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27670401/218196)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[*`Arrow functions`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) do *not* bind its own `this` argument - that is why you get `undefined` -  so you can use the normal function mode:

```
$("#clients-table tbody tr").click(function() {

    let $this = $(this);

    console.log($this);
    console.log($(this));
    console.log($(this).attr("class"));
    console.log($("#clients-table tbody tr").attr("class"));
    console.log("end");
  });
```

Comment: if that is the case then how to use this in the arrow functions?

Comment: @Jai well we can use the normal `function(){}`.. enlighten us if there's any other way you know? :)

Comment: @kukkuz well i was also exploring if there is any way to achieve such thing.

Comment: @Jai: If you use a function as a callback and the code that calls the callback sets the value of `this` (and you want to use `this`), you can't use an arrow function. Arrow functions do not replace "normal" functions.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is probably the more realistic one, but to note, you could also stop using `this` and do

```
$("#clients-table tbody tr").click(evt => {
    let $this = $(evt.currentTarget);

    // ...
});
```