# get complete list of href attribute from website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-scraping

I want to get the complete list of all the `URLs` generated for the YouTube playlist from website whose link structure looks like:

```
<table class="table" id="ListVideo">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td><img style="height: 55px;width: 90px;" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/mHpvT1P_OAM/default.jpg"></td>
            <td>Android Development for Beginner: Brief Overview Of Android</td>
            <td>
                <div id="Download-mHpvT1P_OAM" link="https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?api=youtubemultidownloader.com&amp;mn=sn-p5qlsnz6&amp;signature=B2C601E05D43FADDDDDC595B25F3A77E4CF24FB9.96E1AB91173820178049E0402A3F48E29086AEBB&amp;mime=video%2Fmp4&amp;mt=1492516586&amp;dur=182.415&amp;id=o-AIjyKLM2gc2g7w9RB0izMEVqvaTbIxAJ9iTa0tQakpAb&amp;key=yt6&amp;ip=66.249.83.29&amp;mm=31&amp;mv=m&amp;pl=28&amp;ipbits=0&amp;ms=au&amp;sparams=dur%2Cei%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&amp;expire=1492538256&amp;lmt=1486569580323751&amp;ratebypass=yes&amp;source=youtube&amp;upn=P2VOmq_LKgk&amp;itag=22&amp;requiressl=yes&amp;ei=MP_1WLKeBuKF8gTh35WgDQ&amp;title=01.Android%20Development%20for%20Beginner%3A%20Brief%20Overview%20Of%20Android"><a download="" href="https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?api=youtubemultidownloader.com&amp;mn=sn-p5qlsnz6&amp;signature=B2C601E05D43FADDDDDC595B25F3A77E4CF24FB9.96E1AB91173820178049E0402A3F48E29086AEBB&amp;mime=video%2Fmp4&amp;mt=1492516586&amp;dur=182.415&amp;id=o-AIjyKLM2gc2g7w9RB0izMEVqvaTbIxAJ9iTa0tQakpAb&amp;key=yt6&amp;ip=66.249.83.29&amp;mm=31&amp;mv=m&amp;pl=28&amp;ipbits=0&amp;ms=au&amp;sparams=dur%2Cei%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&amp;expire=1492538256&amp;lmt=1486569580323751&amp;ratebypass=yes&amp;source=youtube&amp;upn=P2VOmq_LKgk&amp;itag=22&amp;requiressl=yes&amp;ei=MP_1WLKeBuKF8gTh35WgDQ&amp;title=01.Android%20Development%20for%20Beginner%3A%20Brief%20Overview%20Of%20Android&amp;title=01.Android%20Development%20for%20Beginner%3A%20Brief%20Overview%20Of%20Android"
                    class="btn btn-default" type="button">MP4 720P</a> </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        .
        . and so on 
        .
        .
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am able to get the individual hrefs from `a tag` using

```
console.log($("#ListVideo td div a").attr("href"))
```

which gives me link
`https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback...0Brief%20Overview%20Of%20Android` I want
but when I try to loop through all the links  with below function

```
$("#ListVideo td div a").each(()=> {console.log($(this).attr("href"))})
```

instead I get undefined.
Here is the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8f0rte4h/2/) link with the complete page source from which I want to get links.
Can someone please tell me where am I going wrong. Thanks

Comment: the solution present there is the same I have tried which is not working

Comment: probably because you are trying to get a href attrbiute off a div (which won't have one)

Comment: sorry forgot to add a tag in here, though I used that to fetch all links, updated my question

Comment: in which case you probably can't do an anonymous function like that in the each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the right methods to get the right `$(this)` - so not an arrow function in this case.

```
var list = [];
$("#ListVideo td div a").each(function() {
  list.push($(this).attr("href"))
});
console.log(list);
```

Using arrow, you need to not use `this` as seen in

[Using jQuery $(this) with ES6 Arrow Functions (lexical this binding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670401/using-jquery-this-with-es6-arrow-functions-lexical-this-binding)

```
var list1 = [];
$("#ListVideo td div a").each((index, element) => {
  list1.push($(element).attr("href"));
});
console.log(list1);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/yr39tmqn/

Comment: Thanks for the info on $(this) and es6 arrow function

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what about selecting the elements based on their attribute, like this `$([href])`?

Secondly, `()=> {console.log($(this).attr("href"))}` logs undefined as arrow funcitons have a different `this`. To put it short, an arrow function does not create its own `this` context, so `this` has its original meaning from the enclosing context. 
You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this). Using a classic `function` would work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8f0rte4h/4/).You can see the number of links exactly logged out to the console.

```
console.log($("#ListVideo td div a").attr("href"));
var hrefArray = [];
$("#ListVideo td div a").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr("href"));
  hrefArray.push($(this).attr("href"));
});

console.log(hrefArray.length);
```

Comment: no difference. couldn't see your answer before posting mine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example, pure javascript code. We use `querySelectorAll` to find all `a`nchors within our `.table` class.

```js
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('.table a');


// pure js
for (i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
  var anchor = anchors[i];
  
  // You can access href attribute via anchor.href
  console.log(anchor.href);
}

// using forEach, we must use Object.keys 
Object.keys(anchors).forEach(function(key) {
    // console.log(anchors[key].href);  // href
});


// using map, we must use Object.keys 
var listOfAnchors = Object.keys(anchors).map(function(key) {
  return anchors[key].href;
});

// Array of anchors inside our table
// console.log(listOfAnchors);
```

```html
<table class="table" id="ListVideo">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td><img style="height: 55px;width: 90px;" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/mHpvT1P_OAM/default.jpg"></td>
            <td>Android Development for Beginner: Brief Overview Of Android</td>
            <td>
                <div id="Download-mHpvT1P_OAM" link="https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?api=youtubemultidownloader.com&amp;mn=sn-p5qlsnz6&amp;signature=B2C601E05D43FADDDDDC595B25F3A77E4CF24FB9.96E1AB91173820178049E0402A3F48E29086AEBB&amp;mime=video%2Fmp4&amp;mt=1492516586&amp;dur=182.415&amp;id=o-AIjyKLM2gc2g7w9RB0izMEVqvaTbIxAJ9iTa0tQakpAb&amp;key=yt6&amp;ip=66.249.83.29&amp;mm=31&amp;mv=m&amp;pl=28&amp;ipbits=0&amp;ms=au&amp;sparams=dur%2Cei%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&amp;expire=1492538256&amp;lmt=1486569580323751&amp;ratebypass=yes&amp;source=youtube&amp;upn=P2VOmq_LKgk&amp;itag=22&amp;requiressl=yes&amp;ei=MP_1WLKeBuKF8gTh35WgDQ&amp;title=01.Android%20Development%20for%20Beginner%3A%20Brief%20Overview%20Of%20Android"><a download="" href="https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?api=youtubemultidownloader.com&amp;mn=sn-p5qlsnz6&amp;signature=B2C601E05D43FADDDDDC595B25F3A77E4CF24FB9.96E1AB91173820178049E0402A3F48E29086AEBB&amp;mime=video%2Fmp4&amp;mt=1492516586&amp;dur=182.415&amp;id=o-AIjyKLM2gc2g7w9RB0izMEVqvaTbIxAJ9iTa0tQakpAb&amp;key=yt6&amp;ip=66.249.83.29&amp;mm=31&amp;mv=m&amp;pl=28&amp;ipbits=0&amp;ms=au&amp;sparams=dur%2Cei%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&amp;expire=1492538256&amp;lmt=1486569580323751&amp;ratebypass=yes&amp;source=youtube&amp;upn=P2VOmq_LKgk&amp;itag=22&amp;requiressl=yes&amp;ei=MP_1WLKeBuKF8gTh35WgDQ&amp;title=01.Android%20Development%20for%20Beginner%3A%20Brief%20Overview%20Of%20Android&amp;title=01.Android%20Development%20for%20Beginner%3A%20Brief%20Overview%20Of%20Android"
                    class="btn btn-default" type="button">MP4 720P</a> </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td><img style="height: 55px;width: 90px;" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/mHpvT1P_OAM/default.jpg"></td>
            <td>Android Development for Beginner: Brief Overview Of Android</td>
            <td>
                <div id="Download-mHpvT1P_OAM" link="https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?api=youtubemultidownloader.com&amp;mn=sn-p5qlsnz6&amp;signature=B2C601E05D43FADDDDDC595B25F3A77E4CF24FB9.96E1AB91173820178049E0402A3F48E29086AEBB&amp;mime=video%2Fmp4&amp;mt=1492516586&amp;dur=182.415&amp;id=o-AIjyKLM2gc2g7w9RB0izMEVqvaTbIxAJ9iTa0tQakpAb&amp;key=yt6&amp;ip=66.249.83.29&amp;mm=31&amp;mv=m&amp;pl=28&amp;ipbits=0&amp;ms=au&amp;sparams=dur%2Cei%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&amp;expire=1492538256&amp;lmt=1486569580323751&amp;ratebypass=yes&amp;source=youtube&amp;upn=P2VOmq_LKgk&amp;itag=22&amp;requiressl=yes&amp;ei=MP_1WLKeBuKF8gTh35WgDQ&amp;title=01.Android%20Development%20for%20Beginner%3A%20Brief%20Overview%20Of%20Android"><a download="" href="https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?api=youtubemultidownloader.com&amp;mn=sn-p5qlsnz6&amp;signature=B2C601E05D43FADDDDDC595B25F3A77E4CF24FB9.96E1AB91173820178049E0402A3F48E29086AEBB&amp;mime=video%2Fmp4&amp;mt=1492516586&amp;dur=182.415&amp;id=o-AIjyKLM2gc2g7w9RB0izMEVqvaTbIxAJ9iTa0tQakpAb&amp;key=yt6&amp;ip=66.249.83.29&amp;mm=31&amp;mv=m&amp;pl=28&amp;ipbits=0&amp;ms=au&amp;sparams=dur%2Cei%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&amp;expire=1492538256&amp;lmt=1486569580323751&amp;ratebypass=yes&amp;source=youtube&amp;upn=P2VOmq_LKgk&amp;itag=22&amp;requiressl=yes&amp;ei=MP_1WLKeBuKF8gTh35WgDQ&amp;title=01.Android%20Development%20for%20Beginner%3A%20Brief%20Overview%20Of%20Android&amp;title=01.Android%20Development%20for%20Beginner%3A%20Brief%20Overview%20Of%20Android"
                    class="btn btn-default" type="button">MP4 720P</a> </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td><img style="height: 55px;width: 90px;" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/mHpvT1P_OAM/default.jpg"></td>
            <td>Android Development for Beginner: Brief Overview Of Android</td>
            <td>
                <div id="Download-mHpvT1P_OAM" link="https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?api=youtubemultidownloader.com&amp;mn=sn-p5qlsnz6&amp;signature=B2C601E05D43FADDDDDC595B25F3A77E4CF24FB9.96E1AB91173820178049E0402A3F48E29086AEBB&amp;mime=video%2Fmp4&amp;mt=1492516586&amp;dur=182.415&amp;id=o-AIjyKLM2gc2g7w9RB0izMEVqvaTbIxAJ9iTa0tQakpAb&amp;key=yt6&amp;ip=66.249.83.29&amp;mm=31&amp;mv=m&amp;pl=28&amp;ipbits=0&amp;ms=au&amp;sparams=dur%2Cei%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&amp;expire=1492538256&amp;lmt=1486569580323751&amp;ratebypass=yes&amp;source=youtube&amp;upn=P2VOmq_LKgk&amp;itag=22&amp;requiressl=yes&amp;ei=MP_1WLKeBuKF8gTh35WgDQ&amp;title=01.Android%20Development%20for%20Beginner%3A%20Brief%20Overview%20Of%20Android"><a download="" href="https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?api=youtubemultidownloader.com&amp;mn=sn-p5qlsnz6&amp;signature=B2C601E05D43FADDDDDC595B25F3A77E4CF24FB9.96E1AB91173820178049E0402A3F48E29086AEBB&amp;mime=video%2Fmp4&amp;mt=1492516586&amp;dur=182.415&amp;id=o-AIjyKLM2gc2g7w9RB0izMEVqvaTbIxAJ9iTa0tQakpAb&amp;key=yt6&amp;ip=66.249.83.29&amp;mm=31&amp;mv=m&amp;pl=28&amp;ipbits=0&amp;ms=au&amp;sparams=dur%2Cei%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&amp;expire=1492538256&amp;lmt=1486569580323751&amp;ratebypass=yes&amp;source=youtube&amp;upn=P2VOmq_LKgk&amp;itag=22&amp;requiressl=yes&amp;ei=MP_1WLKeBuKF8gTh35WgDQ&amp;title=01.Android%20Development%20for%20Beginner%3A%20Brief%20Overview%20Of%20Android&amp;title=01.Android%20Development%20for%20Beginner%3A%20Brief%20Overview%20Of%20Android"
                    class="btn btn-default" type="button">MP4 720P</a> </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td><img style="height: 55px;width: 90px;" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/mHpvT1P_OAM/default.jpg"></td>
            <td>Android Development for Beginner: Brief Overview Of Android</td>
            <td>
                <div id="Download-mHpvT1P_OAM" link="https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?api=youtubemultidownloader.com&amp;mn=sn-p5qlsnz6&amp;signature=B2C601E05D43FADDDDDC595B25F3A77E4CF24FB9.96E1AB91173820178049E0402A3F48E29086AEBB&amp;mime=video%2Fmp4&amp;mt=1492516586&amp;dur=182.415&amp;id=o-AIjyKLM2gc2g7w9RB0izMEVqvaTbIxAJ9iTa0tQakpAb&amp;key=yt6&amp;ip=66.249.83.29&amp;mm=31&amp;mv=m&amp;pl=28&amp;ipbits=0&amp;ms=au&amp;sparams=dur%2Cei%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&amp;expire=1492538256&amp;lmt=1486569580323751&amp;ratebypass=yes&amp;source=youtube&amp;upn=P2VOmq_LKgk&amp;itag=22&amp;requiressl=yes&amp;ei=MP_1WLKeBuKF8gTh35WgDQ&amp;title=01.Android%20Development%20for%20Beginner%3A%20Brief%20Overview%20Of%20Android"><a download="" href="https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?api=youtubemultidownloader.com&amp;mn=sn-p5qlsnz6&amp;signature=B2C601E05D43FADDDDDC595B25F3A77E4CF24FB9.96E1AB91173820178049E0402A3F48E29086AEBB&amp;mime=video%2Fmp4&amp;mt=1492516586&amp;dur=182.415&amp;id=o-AIjyKLM2gc2g7w9RB0izMEVqvaTbIxAJ9iTa0tQakpAb&amp;key=yt6&amp;ip=66.249.83.29&amp;mm=31&amp;mv=m&amp;pl=28&amp;ipbits=0&amp;ms=au&amp;sparams=dur%2Cei%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&amp;expire=1492538256&amp;lmt=1486569580323751&amp;ratebypass=yes&amp;source=youtube&amp;upn=P2VOmq_LKgk&amp;itag=22&amp;requiressl=yes&amp;ei=MP_1WLKeBuKF8gTh35WgDQ&amp;title=01.Android%20Development%20for%20Beginner%3A%20Brief%20Overview%20Of%20Android&amp;title=01.Android%20Development%20for%20Beginner%3A%20Brief%20Overview%20Of%20Android"
                    class="btn btn-default" type="button">MP4 720P</a> </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why bother rewriting the script? It works when using the correct `this`