# debounced function not being called in a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, lodash, es6-class

I have the react component below.
The raiseCriteriaChange method is called but the this.props.onCriteriaChange(this.state.criteria) line is never reached.

Any ideas why the code never reaches **this.props.onCriteriaChange**?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { debounce } from 'lodash';

interface CustomerSearchCriteriaProps {
  onCriteriaChange: (criteria: string) => void;
}
interface CustomerSearchCriteriaState {
  criteria: string;
}

class CustomerSearchCriteria extends React.Component<CustomerSearchCriteriaProps, CustomerSearchCriteriaState> {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      criteria: ''
    };
  }

  // problem method:
  raiseCriteriaChange = () => {
    // the call reaches here fine ...
    debounce(
    () => {
       // ... but the call never reaches here ... why is this?
       this.props.onCriteriaChange(this.state.criteria);
    },  
    300);
  }

  handleCriteriaChange = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    this.setState({ criteria: e.currentTarget.value }, () => {
      this.raiseCriteriaChange();
    });
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="input-group">
        <input
          type="text" 
          value={this.state.criteria} 
          onChange={this.handleCriteriaChange} 
          className="form-control"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CustomerSearchCriteria;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using jQuery $(this) with ES6 Arrow Functions (lexical this binding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670401/using-jquery-this-with-es6-arrow-functions-lexical-this-binding)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`_.debounce`](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce) simply returns a function that must be called. Try changing your code like:

```
raiseCriteriaChange = debounce(() => {
    this.props.onCriteriaChange(this.state.criteria);
}, 300);
```

Answer (score 2):

See [_.debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce), which says it

> (Function): Returns the new debounced function.

so you need to call it like

```
var debounced = debounce(
    () => {
       // ... but the call never reaches here ... why is this?
       this.props.onCriteriaChange(this.state.criteria);
    },  
    300
);

debounced();
```