# Not able to find data-id when selecting element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

Apologies in advance I feel as if this is a very simple solution and I am in the middle of a severe brain fart. I am simply trying to grab the data-id of an item I am clicking using ES6 syntax but no matter which way I run it I keep getting undefined.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="list-item" data-id="item-1">Click me</li>
    <li class="list-item" data-id="item-2">Click me</li>
    <li class="list-item" data-id="item-3">Click me</li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
let $el = $('ul');

class List {
    constructor($el) {
        this.$el = $el;

        this.$listItem = $el.find('li');

        this.attachHandlers();
    }

    attachHandlers() {
        this.$listItem.on('click', () => {
            var data = $(this).attr('data-id');
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
}

const _init = () => {
    if ($el.length) {
        $el.each((i, v) => {
            new List($(v));
        });
    }
};

_init();
```

Ive simplified the code down as much as possible, anybody see what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `attachHandlers` method. Since you are using an arrow function, `this` refers to the class and not the element that was clicked.

Change the arrow function to a regular function.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Josan's answer, if you want to continue using the arrow function, use it like this:

```
class List {
    constructor($el) {
        this.$el = $el;
        this.attachHandlers();
    }

    attachHandlers() {
        this.$el.on('click', 'li', (e) => {
            var data = $(e.currentTarget).attr('data-id');
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
}
```

For more discussion, refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670401/using-jquery-this-with-es6-arrow-functions-lexical-this-binding).

Comment: this seems to return the data-id content of the first element in the list, not of the element that has been clicked. If I pass the event through and console.log e.currentTarget I can see the correct element but it always returns the data-id of the first element

Comment: @user934902 -- Yes, because your constructor always sets the first `li` as `this.$listItem`.

Comment: then I am confused about your answer on how using the arrow function as you have described will solve my issue

Comment: @user934902 -- Please see my updated answer. That should solve the issue. You don't need to use `$listItem`.

Answer (score -2):

Simpler and easier by just using JQuery:

```js
$(".list-item").on('click', function() {
  console.log($(this).data('id'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="list-item" data-id="item-1">Click me</li>
  <li class="list-item" data-id="item-2">Click me</li>
  <li class="list-item" data-id="item-3">Click me</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: He is using jQuery