# I get 'TypeError: t.nodeName is undefined' whevever I use 'this' keyword to iterate through and get values from the input fields in my HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML form with some input fields and I want to check for empty fields using jQuery by using the `this` keyword but I can't figure out the reason of error that I'm getting:

> TypeError: t.nodeName is undefined

This is the javscript code of what i've tried:

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
    $("#submit-btn").click(()=>{
        $(".myform input").each(()=>{    
            if($(this).val().length == 0) {
                $(this).css("border", "2px solid red");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I can't figure out why I am getting the error because I saw someone suggest this exact code in some another similar question but I can't get the output I expected. So before you mark this question for 'duplicate', at least help me with the answer.

Comment: Try using `function(){}` instead of the arrow function. Maybe similar problems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670401/using-jquery-this-with-es6-arrow-functions-lexical-this-binding) and [here](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/jquery-this-selector-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `this` inside the arrow function. You should use the second argument of the `each` function to gain access to the element.

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
    $("#submit-btn").click(()=>{
        $(".myform input").each((idx, element)=>{    
            if($(element).val().length == 0) {
                $(element).css("border", "2px solid red");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks so much. I didn't know i had to use the parameters of each() method.