# $(this) refers to $(window) instead of clicked element inside .click() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to access child elements within an unordered list, but I'm not getting the values I expected.

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<ul id="weekdayList">
  <li>
    <label for="sunday">S</label>
    <input id="sunday" type="checkbox" name="sunday">
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="monday">M</label>
    <input id="monday" type="checkbox" name="monday">
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="tuesday">T</label>
    <input id="tuesday" type="checkbox" name="tuesday">
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="wednesday">W</label>
    <input id="wednesday" type="checkbox" name="wednesday">
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="thursday">T</label>
    <input id="thursday" type="checkbox" name="thursday">
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="friday">F</label>
    <input id="friday" type="checkbox" name="friday">
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="saturday">S</label>
    <input id="saturday" type="checkbox" name="saturday">
  </li>
</ul>
```

And the JS code:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  // Make labels active when corresponding checkbox is checked
  $('#weekdayList label').click((event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();

    console.log($(this));
    console.log($('#weekdayList li:nth-child(2) label'));
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

CodePen here: https://codepen.io/mattmc318/pen/mdyEeJy

When I click on the 'M' `label`, for example, I expect the output of `console.log($(this));` to be the same as `console.log($('#weekdayList li:nth-child(2) label'));`.

Instead of this:

```js
Object { 0: label, length: 1, prevObject: Object(1) }
```

I get this:

```js
Object [ Window ]
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to made the click event function on outside of document.ready ?

Comment: Yes, it didn't change anything.

Comment: It's because `this` inside an arrow function is in its higher scoped context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're using arrow function, so, $(this) is not correctly.
Instead of

```
$('#weekdayList label').click((event) => {
});
```

Please use this:

```
$('#weekdayList label').click(function (event) {
    // You can use $(this) here
});
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything. Even when I changed the function inside `$(document).ready();`, the output is the same and the labels don't change color.

Comment: This helped, actually, but my click function is being called twice. That's why I thought this change didn't help earlier. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @MattMcCarthy what did you see that indicates the click event is being fired twice?

Comment: The output was doubled in the code example, but not my original code. I was targeting `#weekdayList li` in my example, but it only fires once when I changed it back. Problem solved. Thanks, all!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  // Make labels active when corresponding checkbox is checked
  /*$("#weekdayList li").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    
    console.log($(this));
    console.log($('#weekdayList li:nth-child(2) label'));
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  })*/
  
  $('#weekdayList li').click((event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    
    console.log($(event.currentTarget));
    console.log($('#weekdayList li:nth-child(2) label'));
    $(event.currentTarget).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

arrow function is ES6, this not always target to current element. please refer to [jQuery this with ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670401/using-jquery-this-with-es6-arrow-functions-lexical-this-binding)