# Toggle hide class only on selected div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a UL with API generated LI's(users). Inside each user, there is a hidden container with inputs for adding tags to search by. These hidden containers are supposed to show on ONLY the selected user when you click a "+" pseudo-button.

I had it working to toggle the hide class, but it toggles on every generated class, and not the specific user I click on.

jQuery Code:

```
$(".fa-plus").on("click", (() =>{
    $("#tag-container, #add-tag-input, #hideGrades",() => {
        $(this).toggleClass("hidden");
    });
}));
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="hideGrades">
  <p class="card-text hidden">Grades: <%= grades %></p> 
</div>  
<div class="tag-container hidden" id="tag-container">
</div>
<div>
<input class ="hidden" type="text" value="" placeholder="Add a tag" id="add-tag-input" />
</div>
```

Full Div:

```
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h2 class="card-title"><%=student["firstName"] + " " + student["lastName"] %> <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></h2>
                            <div>
                                <p class="card-text">Email: <%= student["email"] %></p>
                                <p class="card-text">Company: <%= student["company"] %></p>
                                <p class="card-text">Skill: <%= student["skill"] %></p>
                                </p>
                                <div id="hideGrades">
                                    <p class="card-text hidden">Grades: <%= student["grades"] %></p>    
                                </div>
                                <div class="tag-container hidden" id="tag-container">
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                  <input class ="hidden" type="text" value="" placeholder="Add a tag" id="add-tag-input" />
                                </div>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can NOT use `this` in an arrow function. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670401/using-jquery-this-with-es6-arrow-functions-lexical-this-binding)

Comment: Where does your + sign appear ? in that can you add that in your HTML.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Thanks for the tip, I added the HTML code you requested.

Comment: added the full Div for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can amend your HTML you make it more easy and simply use jQuery functions like `parent()` and `siblings()` to show the items where you click at only and not all classes in your DOM.

> Also you do not need to use arrow functions and `this` => in `jQuery` it will make things complicated.

You can simply use `function` to do  the same thing.

Run snippet below to see working (Click on **+** sign so the hidden fields are displayed for each student)

```js
$(".fa-plus").on("click", function(){
    $(this).parent().siblings('.grades_section').toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h2 class="card-title">Student 1 <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></h2>
    <div>
      <p class="card-text">Email: Email
      </p>
      <p class="card-text">Company: Company
      </p>
      <p class="card-text">Skill: Skill
      </p>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="grades_section hidden">
      <div id="hideGrades">
        <p class="card-text ">Grades: grades</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tag-container" id="tag-container">
        Some Data
      </div>
      <div>
        <input class="add-tag-input" type="text" value="" placeholder="Add a tag" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h2 class="card-title">Student 2 <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></h2>
    <div>
      <p class="card-text">Email: Email
      </p>
      <p class="card-text">Company: Company
      </p>
      <p class="card-text">Skill: Skill
      </p>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="grades_section hidden">
      <div id="hideGrades">
        <p class="card-text ">Grades: grades</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tag-container" id="tag-container">
        Some Data
      </div>
      <div>
        <input class="add-tag-input" type="text" value="" placeholder="Add a tag" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```