# Get the value of a radio input button using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the value of the radio button that has been clicked, and I'm using the code below.
But I'm getting the following error:

**jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined**

The code that I have used:

```
$(()=> {
  $("input:radio").click(()=>{
    alert($(this).val())
  })
})
```

Comment: Arrow functions `=>` does not work well with jQuery. `$(this)` refer to the window not the element itself. Use normal function like this > `$("input:radio").click(function(){})`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using jQuery $(this) with ES6 Arrow Functions (lexical this binding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670401/using-jquery-this-with-es6-arrow-functions-lexical-this-binding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are using an arrow function, so `this` refers to whatever it refered to outside of that function (it won't refer to the clicked element).

```js
$(()=> {
  $("input:radio").click(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="demo">
    <input type="radio" name="demo" value="a"/> A
</label>
<label for="demo">
    <input type="radio" name="demo" value="b"/> B
</label>
<label for="demo">
    <input type="radio" name="demo" value="c"/> C
</label>
<label for="demo">
    <input type="radio" name="demo" value="d"/> D
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message has nothing to do with the code you provided, it is recommended to check the `Chrome plugin` `or other codes`

Answer (score 0):

Just use the easier built in `:checked` parameter with the `val()` function

```
$('input[name="name_of_your_radiobutton"]:checked').val();
```