# what's i'm doing wrong in callback function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

My callback function is not working. What am I doing wrong?

```html
<script>
 $("button").click(fnction(){
  $("p").hide("slow", function(){
    alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
  });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Next time, use your browser's dev-tools to check for errors

Answer (score 1):

the word ***function*** is misspelled

```
$("button").click(fnction(){
```

Fix it.

```
$("button").click(function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. Use arrow functions for callbacks.

```
<script>
 $("button").click(() => {
  $("p").hide("slow", () => {
    alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
  });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Using arrow functions with jQuery comes with its own set of pitfalls. Not really recommended

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me a reference?

Comment: [Using jQuery $(this) with ES6 Arrow Functions (lexical this binding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670401/using-jquery-this-with-es6-arrow-functions-lexical-this-binding)

Comment: Thanks. However the 'this' keyword is not used in this particular solution.