# How do we access the next element?

Tags: html, jquery

How do I access `.show-video-player` if someone clicks on `.video-play-pause`? This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work.

```js
$('.video-play-pause').on('click', (e) => {
  $(this).parent().next('.show-video-player').toggle();
  alert($(this).parent().next('.show-video-player').length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lesson">
  <div class="video-play-pause" data-url="{{url}}">video-play-pause</div>
</div>
<div class="show-video-player">show-video-player</div>
```

Comment: Hi try accessing it like this `$(event.currentTarget).parent().next('.show-video-player').toggle();` .Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27670450/10606400) answer to know reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When accessing the `parent` of the clicked element, use event instead of `this` keyword.
So you can change your selector to below:
`$(e.target).parent().next('.show-video-player').toggle()`