# Why the result is not the same lamda vs function

Tags: jquery

i have 2 samples:

i have result `undefined` with this syntax using lambda:

```
  $.each($("ul"), () => {   
    console.log('lambda ' + $(this).attr("class") );
  });
```

its ok with this syntax using function():

```
  $.each($("ul"), function() {    
    console.log('function ' + $(this).attr("class") );
  });
```

I would understant why the results are differents. I'am thinking the syntax are equivalent. I am wrong?

Comment: Fat arrow function does not bind `this`

Comment: In your situation, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34199426/519413) in the duplicate contains the solution you need

Comment: @Rory McCrossan thanks, i didnt see that in my searches..