# Typescript unable to read object's ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have the following event handler defined:

```
$('#current-tab').click(myCode.handleTabClick);
```

And in that function I have

```
handleTabClick: (): void => {
    const identifier: string = $(this).attr('id');
},
```

When I execute this in the browser, the event gets fired but I see `identifier` is "undefined".  However,  if I add a break-point and then copy `$(this).attr('id')` into the browser's console, I see that this resolves to "current-tab".

Why can't I capture this into my constant variable?

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible example? It is very hard to tell from the information you provided.

Comment: Handle click is an arrow function. Change it to a regular function. The “this” context is not bound to the function in an arrow function

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27670450/10606400) answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-interchangeable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
handleTabClick: (): void => {
    const identifier: string = $(this).attr('id');

},
```

To:

```
handleTabClick: function(): void {
    const identifier: string = $(this).attr('id');
}
```

In a an arrow function `this` is not bound to the function